Unable to delete directory in intContainer
I have created an initContainer
initContainers:
        - name: migration
          image: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:latest
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsNonRoot: true
            
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /tmp/import_export/ && cp /tmp/migration/* /tmp/import_export/ && rm -rf /tmp/migration/*']
          volumeMounts:
            - name: backup-config-volume
              mountPath: /tmp/migration/
            - name: dest
              mountPath: /tmp/import_export/

``
which has  shared volume /tmp/migration , /tmp/import_export/  with main container
if i just copy files from /tmp/migration to /tmp/import_export/
command: ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /tmp/import_export/ && cp /tmp/migration/* /tmp/import_export/']


it works
but if I try to remove files in source directory after copy by adding rm -rf /tmp/migration/* in existing command
command: ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /tmp/import_export/ && cp /tmp/migration/* /tmp/import_export/ && rm -rf /tmp/migration/*']

it fails could you suggest any workaround so that I can remove files from source directory after copy completes ?

How does it fail?  What is the backup-config-volume?

backup-config-volume is a volume which has embed files by a secret  name: backup-config-volume
secret:
secretName: backup-config
optional: true

You can't edit Secrets that way.  I'd expect you'll see the mounted filesystem is read-only, which would produce some sort of "permission denied" error.

is there some way to delete files from this readonly filesystem ? i tried moving files instead of copy i.e. mv /src/ to /dest it also failed

Why are you trying to delete the file?  Are you in fact trying to modify the Secret object, or is there some other use case that requires the files to not be present in the container filesystem?

if i copy files from this readonly volume it will be processed at destination directory there is no need to have these files at source after copying completes.
